# Nested scss not working properly as expected

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sass, node-sass, sass-loader

I am having an issue while nesting a import in a class like

```
.base-class-xirLd4a709  {
  @import 'semantic.css';
  .deal-icon {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  }
}
```

Imported css is effecting outside of parent class and effecting the whole page. How to make it block scope?

Comment: This should happen automatically if you are compiling the file into the standard CSS. Did you inspect the resultant code?

Comment: Yes i am compiling the code to css using sass-loader and webpack.

Comment: And what is the actual compiled code of the posted fragment?